# What is the difference between, say, 'thousands' and 'thousands and thousands'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does 'thousands and thousands', or 'millions and millions', etc. (something American president Donald Trump would say, for example) mean that it's at least four thousand (2+2)? Or does it mean nothing more than simply 'thousands' so 'thousands and thousands' can even mean 2 thousand?

Comment: In my opinion, it's just dramatic and superlative effect. When you say 'thousands and thousands' you're not necessarily implying 'two thousands'.

Comment: Approximately speaking, 'Thousands' = two or more thousand. 'Thousands and thousands' = many thousand.

Comment: I agree with both answers. The perfect answer is a combination of the two.